# All users can read SSAS all Cubes

Tags: permissions, database-administration, sql-server

I found that all my domainusers can read the cubes in my Microsoft Analasys Services. I have no roles specifying that. Neither the domain admins nor the local admins contain any group that would contain unwanted users. The serveradmin role does not contain any entry. So I'm out of options. Is there any way to determine "how" or "due to which permission" a user accesses SSAS?

Things to mention: the datasource of the cubes use the system account (ImpersonateServiceAccount). But I would wonder if this has anything to do with the issue I have. The properties of the SSAS instance are all on default (except for the file paths).

Could this be related with NTFS permissions on the SSAS's files?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is open BIDs then go into your analysis services project and define the roles. Once you have opened a role go to the membership tab and edit the users who are able to use this according to your needs. Hope that helps.